# how to add 'url' as a data field in Employee details?

Tags: java, url

I am trying to build a simple Employee App in spring boot which uses H2,

The Employee details include the following fields - name, profession and empProfileUrl,

So far, I've implemented the app with basic CRUD operations, but have not added the data field 'empProfileUrl' to it? Please can someone suggest how can I code this? All my other fields are of String data type, Not sure how to add this to table?

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private String profession;
??? empProfileUrl;
```

Comment: Why not simply make it a String?

Comment: That's definitely a String. :)

Comment: Thank you MikeM and ILya Cyclone, I was just overthinking about it then, thanks again :)  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the URL a String, cause that's what a URL really is.

I'm not sure what you're doing, but if you have a method that needs to launch the URL in a browser, it should be accepting the URL as a String- otherwise, I'd look into that documentation.

Let me know if that makes any sense!

Comment: thank you :) I just adding some basic rest api methods and have added url as a String now.